# sort array with its index

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP sort multidimensional array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/php-sort-multidimensional-array-by-value)

I have an array like this -

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rest_id] => 1
            [restname] => Baumgart's Cafe
            [address] => 158 Franklin Avenue
            [distance] => 20.3599115829
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [rest_id] => 2
            [restname] => Brownstone Diner & Pancake Factory
            [address] => 426 Jersey Avenue
            [distance] => 12.422657991
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [rest_id] => 3
            [restname] => Jacques Torres Chocolate
            [address] => 285 Amsterdam Avenue
            [distance] => 16.3264917908
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [rest_id] => 4
            [restname] => Ed's Health Food
            [address] => 150 Mountain Avenue
            [distance] => 31.1066764629
        )
```

I want to sort this array on distance. 
Any help is appreciated.
Thnak you.

Comment: using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php ?

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be done using `usort` and a callback.

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
  $ret = ($a['distance'] - $b['distance']); // this should actually be a subtraction with a comparison to a small epsilon value due to inconsistencies with floating point arithmetic

  if ($ret)
  {
    $ret = ($ret > 0 ? 1 : -1);
  }

  return $ret;
}

usort($array, 'cmp');
```

Comment: The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Comment: This subarrays does not matter the result. The point is your callback should return an integer.

Comment: check this. http://codepad.viper-7.com/HD6rG3

Comment: touche - php not handling floats in the callback for a comparison function is very lame. Answer fixed.

Comment: More info about comparing floats with epsilon values here - basically 1.1 - 0.1 does not always come out to 1.0 which is why the epsilon trick is needed for accuracy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison

Comment: This answer has logical errors. If the two distances are the same, you will (in a non-obvious way) return `-1`

Comment: @Emil - that is, actually, ok for the sorting - although not what was intended - fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
usort($array, function($a,$b){
    if ($a['distance'] === $b['distance']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['distance'] < $b['distance']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: thanks, might be helpful

Comment: To the downvoter, please tell the reason.

Comment: Actually, (likely due to compiler optimization) this answer, and both of my current answers run in the same number of operations.  My original answer (simple subtraction) is, in fact, faster - but doesn't work correctly due to returning of floats rather than ints.  Php just lost some of my respect.

Answer (score 0):

```
usort($array, function($a,$b){
    return (($a['distance'] == $b['distance']) ? 0 : (($a['distance'] > $b['distance']) ? 1 : -1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though php says that it you should return 0 for equal answers, it is only necessary for resorting an already sorted array and preserving the previous sort as a "sub-sort".  This does, in fact, work:

```
function cmp($a, $b) 
{
  return ($a['distance'] - $b['distance'] > 0 ? 1 : -1);
}

usort($array, 'cmp');
```

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/6RLCYM